Gazebo Harmonic - gazebo.material error
I just installed gazebo harmonic on a fresh install of ubuntu 24.04
I'm trying to run a world which works in another machine that I have but I'm getting a weird error:
[Err] [Server.cc:203] Error Code 14: Msg: Parser configurations requested resolved uris, but uri [file:///media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material] could not be resolved.
Any idea on how to solve this?
If more details are needed let me know
Thanks!

I encountered a problem with the simulation from warehouse.sdf
xml
# warehouse.sdf has this asset:
<uri>
   https://fuel.gazebosim.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/models/Table
</uri>

# model.sdf of the Table (can be found in cached objects in your system)
<visual name="front_left_leg">
    ...
    <material>
        <diffuse>0.5 0.5 0.5</diffuse>
        <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
        </script>
    </material>
</visual>

The issue arose because I had gazebo.materials from Gazebo Harmonic installed as /usr/share/gz/gz-sim8/media/gazebo.material
To fix this, I added dummy directories and a symlink to the actual file:
/usr/share/gz/gz-sim8/media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material --> /usr/share/gz/gz-sim8/media/gazebo.material
This works together with this line in ~/.bashrc:
bash

export GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/share/gz/gz-sim8/:$GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH

